# Python indent rules different for interpreter vs command line?

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

Why does:

```
if False:
    print 1
print 2
```

work if I save it as a file and run it from the command line, but if I  try to run it in the interpreter, it gives me an indent error?

To be clear, the intended output is: 2.

Comment: Since you're getting an `indent error` you must be typing it incorrectly. That's all. If you type it in OK it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the interpreter, you need to add an extra newline before the last line:

```
>>> if False:
...     print 1
...
>>> print 2
2
>>>
```

Adding that extra newline lets the interpreter know that the preceding code block is finished.

---

You should notice the symbols before each of the lines.  If the symbol is a `...`, it means that we are still in the previous code block.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something along those lines. But doesn't it make it harder to write code/debug if the behavior of the two is different? Why not just assume that the coder knows what he is doing and that the if-block is finished if the next line has no indent?

Comment: Noone uses IDLE to write complex software.

Comment: @psb - That's just the way the Python dev team implemented the interpreter.  I'm sure they had a good reason, but I must confess that I myself have wished for that behavior in the past. :)

Comment: Is it considered better practice to leave a space or not in such cases? I looked in the Google style guide and don't see it. Also, isn't it convenient to test small blocks of code in the interpreter?

Comment: @psb - Regarding your first question, that is ultimately up to you. :)  Do what looks nice and is easy to read.  Regarding your second, there is nothing wrong with using IDLE to test small stuff quickly.  Although it is usually faster to just fire up the interpreter in the commandline instead of launch IDLE.

Comment: @psb - for interactive development, check out [IPython](http://ipython.org) - it's a supercharged version of the interpreter with about a million extra features. Once you try it you won't want to go back :)